# Changing current cmake generator

Tags: c++, cmake

How can I change current cmake generator **without using Cmake GUI** (I want to change standart generator to Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64)?

Comment: You can use the `-G` option [(generator)](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/Eclipse_CDT4_Generator). Something like `cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"`. Try `cmake --help` to see all the options available in your machine.

Comment: It is a good question. Wonder why no one upvotes it.

Comment: you should specify the generator along with <source> and <build> directory like cmake -G "generator_type" -S <source_path> -B <build_path>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot reliably *change* the generator used for an output (= binary) directory once generation has already happened there once. You should start in a fresh output directory.

Once there, simply use CMake's `-G` [command-line option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake.1.html):

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64"
```

Answer (score 56):

For those seeking the CMake GUI answer.

Using the GUI menu
Go to File->Delete Cache and then click Configure again.

---

A scenario where changing the generator is needed is that you are keeping the CMake GUI open and reusing the same directory (source and CMakeList.txt) to do simple examples or tutorials and deleting the build files before starting again, e.g. with out-of-source build it would be the entire build directory. This is not the standard use case for CMake but one that would be common among beginners.

Comment: Interestingly, even though the question specifically asked for a method that doesn't use the CMake GUI, Google sends people here when they ask for a way to change the generator with the GUI! How confusing.

Comment: Also consider [CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html)