# vscode cmake mvsc compiler not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I downloaded vscode with (C/C++ and cmake extentions) and Visual Studio Tools 2022. Created and QuickStart project with the cmake extention which is a simple:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(hello-cmake VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(hello-cmake main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

but I keep getting this error:

```sh
[variant] Loaded new set of variants
[kit] Successfully loaded 4 kits from C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\CMakeTools\cmake-tools-kits.json
[visual-studio] Patch Windows SDK bin path from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86 to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86 for C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -Sc:/Users/Will/source/hello-cmake -Bc:/Users/Will/source/hello-cmake/build -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"
[main] Configuring folder: hello-cmake 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -Sc:/Users/Will/source/hello-cmake -Bc:/Users/Will/source/hello-cmake/build -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is unknown
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
[cmake]   No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
[cmake]   No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] See also "C:/Users/Will/source/hello-cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[cmake] See also "C:/Users/Will/source/hello-cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
[visual-studio] Patch Windows SDK bin path from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86 to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86 for C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat
```

this is the CMakeError

```sh
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.1.0+ae57d105c for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 4/1/2022 5:43:21 PM.
Project "C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W0 /Gd /TC /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCCompilerId.c
  CMakeCCompilerId.c
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdC.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdC.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdC.lib" /MACHINE:X64 Debug\CMakeCCompilerId.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib' [C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(Link target) -> 
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib' [C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.60


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.1.0+ae57d105c for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 4/1/2022 5:43:21 PM.
Project "C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W0 /Gd /TC /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCCompilerId.c
  CMakeCCompilerId.c
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdC.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdC.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdC.lib" /MACHINE:X64 Debug\CMakeCCompilerId.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib' [C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(Link target) -> 
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib' [C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.43


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.1.0+ae57d105c for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 4/1/2022 5:43:22 PM.
Project "C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W0 /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdCXX.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdCXX.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdCXX.lib" /MACHINE:X64 Debug\CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib' [C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(Link target) -> 
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib' [C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.44


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.1.0+ae57d105c for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 4/1/2022 5:43:23 PM.
Project "C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W0 /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdCXX.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdCXX.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdCXX.lib" /MACHINE:X64 Debug\CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib' [C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(Link target) -> 
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib' [C:\Users\Will\source\hello-cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3.22.22022201-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.44
```

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of [CMake cannot open "ucrtd.lib"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145118/cmake-cannot-open-ucrtd-lib)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71418520/6656422

10.0.19041.0is a bad windows sdk version. I installed 10.0.20348.0 and it works no problem.