# Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2015 Code Migration

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I am trying to generate a solution file using CMake, but during the generation of the solution i am getting the below error. We getting the build tools error as below:

> C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(55,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2010 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".

I have installed VS2015 in my PC and i don't have access to install VS2010, So can somebody help me to generate the solution without the VS2010 installation.
Any Alternate solution to use Visual Studio 2015 build tools instead of using Visual Studio 2010 build tools?..

Comment: What generator are you using?

Comment: Are in invoking CMake from within the VS2015 Developer Command Prompt?

Comment: Try to specifically name the toolset you want in the `cmake` command line: `-T "v140"`. It I have to guess: you just didn't delete your binary output directory before you re-generated the solution with the VS2015 generator.

Comment: @Torbjörn This should not be necessary on a working installation. CMake is able to correctly detect the matching Visual Studio version from the environment variables set by VS's installer. This even works when having multiple versions of VS installed at the same time.

Comment: @Florian Thank you so much for your input. I can able to generate the solution and now trying to build the same.

Comment: @user3367938 You're welcome. I added an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Try to specifically name the toolset you want in the cmake command line:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15" -T "v140"
```

But since this is the default toolset for [visual-studio-2015](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015), you most probably just didn't delete your binary output directory before you re-generated the solution with the VS2015 generator.

Deleting your binary output directory before switching the generator is mandatory in CMake.

**References**

- [Changing current cmake generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569800/changing-current-cmake-generator)